# C# Multi-threaded application to created sql databases / Error : Lock request time out period exceeded. Script execution error

Tags: c#, t-sql

We have a multi threaded C# windows forms application to create multiple databases (say 100 databases like DB1, DB2, ...DB100).
And i have set 15 threads to run concurrently which means 15 database creations happen parallelly. 
Out of 100 databases, i see few databases failed to created like some 10 or 11 databases failed to create with the follwing error.

Can any one suggest a solution for this problem..

Error:

```
------------
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1222, Level 16, State 51, Line 1 Lock request time out period exceeded.
Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
    LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Comment: can you please refer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23335/lock-request-time-out-period-exceeded-error-when-trying-to-see-db-hierarchies/25752

Comment: it is possible that your server ran out or memory or CPU is too busy

Comment: What happens if you drop from 15 to 8 threads?

Comment: Creating a database locks the `model` database. When creating a single database takes too long, you can get such errors (see [this for more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/poojakamath/2014/12/23/could-not-obtain-exclusive-lock-on-database-model-retry-the-operation-later-create-database-failed/)).

Comment: I just tried to drop my concurrent thread count to 7 and observed no issues. Again increased to 10 threads and got this issue.. :( Rate of failure is becoming less if i reduce my thread count

Comment: Adding new databases will lock tables in the system database where it stores metadata. Thus, there will be a point where you can't add an extra database without it timing out. That is what you are experiencing. As such, just use 7 threads rather than 15.

Comment: Thanks All.mjwills